# Displaying Binary of Each Character in a String

Tags: c, string, binary, newline

I have figured out how to get user's input (string) and take each letter from them and give a binary equivalent of each letter.

The problem is I want each letter to give a binary number by having one letter per line when displaying on screen. I would like help in doing so.

For example:

```
C 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
h 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
a 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
n 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
g 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
```

This is the code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    //get input
    printf( "Enter a string: " );
    char s[255];
    scanf( "%[^\n]s" , s );

    //print output 
    printf( "'%s' converted to binary is: " , s );

    //for each character, print it's binary aoutput
    int i,c,power;

    for( i=0 ; s[i]!='\0' ; i++ )
    {
        //c holds the character being converted
        c = s[i];

        //for each binary value below 256 (because ascii values < 256)
        for( power=7 ; power+1 ; power-- )
        //if c is greater than or equal to it, it is a 1
        if( c >= (1<<power) )
        {
            c -= (1<<power); //subtract that binary value
            printf("1");
        }
        //otherwise, it is a zero
        else
            printf("0");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're doing all the hard work already, I don't see where your problem is

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `printf("\n")` statement after you process each character.

```
for( i=0 ; s[i]!='\0' ; i++ )
    {
        //c holds the character being converted
        c = s[i];

        //for each binary value below 256 (because ascii values < 256)
        for( power=7 ; power+1 ; power-- )
        //if c is greater than or equal to it, it is a 1
        if( c >= (1<<power) )
        {
            c -= (1<<power); //subtract that binary value
            printf("1");
        }
        //otherwise, it is a zero
        else
            printf("0");

        /* Add the following statement, for this to work as you expected */
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing your `1`and `0`immediately, build a string from them. Then print out the character you just converted next to the string you just built.

Answer (score 0):

To print each character on a new line, print a newline after printing each character:

```
printf("\n");
```

To print the character first, use putchar:

```
putchar(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the bad code style, it seems what you are looking for is a simple

```
printf("\n");
```

statement immediately following the `printf("0");` in the end of the outer for loop to add newlines.